# Do Two IDENTICAL Bodies Cancel-out Each-other's Gravity?

Tags: gravity, spacetime

If we were to imagine two objects suspended in space* that were identical, with the exact same number of atoms, would the gravitational forces produced by each cancel each-other out? (maintain their separation)
Like two equally buff bodybuilders pulling on the same rope?
Or would they CONSUME the rope (space-time) like the "Lady and the Tramp" eating spaghetti and eventually touch?

Let's also suppose that the two objects are one object space apart; so there's one object, the space one object measures, and then the second object.

I think it's quite clear I have no scholastic credentials, please go easy on me!,
Thanks, Joe!

*(by space I mean a void bereft of other gravitational forces and even the expanding of the Universe)

Answer (score 4):

"Do two identical bodies cancel out each other's gravity?"

In general, no. According to [Newton's law of universal gravitation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_law_of_universal_gravitation) the two bodies will attract each other with a force that is proportional to the product of their masses and inversely proportional to the distance between them. Ignoring other gravitational influences, and assuming the bodies are initially stationary with respect to one another (so not in orbit) then they will get closer together and eventually touch.

However, there is a specific point in space between the two bodies where their gravitational attraction cancels out *at that point only*. For identical spheres this is the point mid way between their centres.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick answer! I see... So we have a "Lady and the Tramp" situation.

Comment: @JoeExclamation Yes, in the sense that the bodies move towards one another. But there is no equivalent of the spaghetti - spacetime is curved because of the presence of the bodies but nothing is being "consumed".